# Two way databinding is not working with knockout ObservableArrays

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, data-binding, knockout.js

I have following code, which has two functions.

1. On click of 'Add more' push a new value to observable array add new text boxe to UI
2. On click of Save display the values in the text box on a div.

```js
var model = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.inventoryItems = ko.observableArray();

  myArray = ["Value1", "V1lue2", "Value3", "Value4"];
  self.inventoryItems(myArray);

  self.addItems = function(vm) {
    self.inventoryItems.push('New Item');
  }

  self.SaveInventory = function(data) {
    $('#htmlBlock').html(myArray);
    console.log(myArray)
  };

};

ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.info-text,
a,
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: inventoryItems">
  <li>
    <input data-bind="value: $data" />
  </li>
</ul>
<div>
  <a data-bind="click: addItems">+ Add more</a>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-accent" data-bind="click: SaveInventory">Save changes</button>
<div class='info-text' id="htmlBlock">
</div>
```

With this code my UI is initializing fine and when I click on 'Add more' , able to get a new text box and myArray/inventoryItems is also working fine.

But if I edit any item and save the value, I am not getting the update value back.

What am I missing?

Comment: @xec, Are you refering to  $('#htmlBlock') as Vew code? This is just for demonstration.

Comment: Can any one please explain what needs to be improved , not to be downvoted? I have provided a fiddle , snippet and explained my query? So why the down votes?

Comment: It was unclear what you were asking. Following the 2 steps at the start it was working fine. I didn't see that it was the input field values themselves that you were struggling with. I have updated my answer. it might also be because you posted 4 very similar questions in short succession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a separate reference to the underlying array in the observable array, it only confuses things. Read out the value by using `self.inventoryItems()`.

A good way to see what your model looks like in real time is using an element with `data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, '\t')"`

In order to have two-way binding you need to make each value (for the input fields) observable. Usually i would use a separate constructor for this.

```js
function EditableField(initialValue) {
  // each value you want to be able to have a two-way binding for needs to be observable
  this.value = ko.observable(initialValue);
}

var model = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.inventoryItems = ko.observableArray(["Value1", "V1lue2", "Value3", "Value4"].map(function(item) {
    // run each array value through constructor
    return new EditableField(item);
  }));

  self.addItems = function(vm) {
    self.inventoryItems.push(new EditableField('New Item'));
  }

  self.SaveInventory = function(data) {
    console.log(ko.toJS(self.inventoryItems)); // fetch the updated array
  };

};

ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.info-text,
a,
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: inventoryItems">
  <li>
    <!-- use textInput binding for live updates, bound to the value property from constructor -->
    <input data-bind="textInput: value" />
  </li>
</ul>
<div>
  <a data-bind="click: addItems">+ Add more</a>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-accent" data-bind="click: SaveInventory">Save changes</button>

<!-- display the model in real time -->
<pre class='info-text' data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, '\t')">
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not update the values when I edit a value in text box and click save. This is  my original question.

Comment: Thanks so much ,  ko.observable(initialValue); and .map are awesome pointers any one who is just starting with KO. I will also keep in mind not mixing the UI code

Comment: You're welcome :) Note that `.map()` has nothing to do with knockout, it is a native javascript loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map